# java.io.IOException: write failed: EBADF (Bad file number)

Tags: android, fileoutputstream

I am having an issue while writing to an internal file(files-folder). Here I am trying to backup my logs to a file inside files folder. Here is my code.

```
package com.rss.feedster.rss_feedster.utility;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.util.Log;

import com.rss.feedster.rss_feedster.R;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class LogBackup {

    private static LogBackup log = null;
    private static FileOutputStream fos = null;
    private static Date dateTimeStamp;
    private static final String TAG = Constants.TAG+" : "+LogBackup.class.getSimpleName();

    private LogBackup(){
        dateTimeStamp = new Date();
    }

    private static String getDateTime(Date date) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }

    public static LogBackup getLogBackup(FileOutputStream fos){
        if(log==null)
            log = new LogBackup();

        log.fos = fos;
        return log;
    }

    public static void writeLog(String msg) {
        if(fos!=null) {
            try {
                fos.write((getDateTime(dateTimeStamp)+"  "+msg+"\n").getBytes());
                fos.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "fos = null");
        }
    }

}
```

Here fos is obtained using `openFileOutput` method.

I get the following error

```
java.io.IOException: write failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:502)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:186)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:82)
    at **com.rss.feedster.rss_feedster.utility.LogBackup.writeLog(LogBackup.java:47)**
    at com.rss.feedster.rss_feedster.sync.FeedsterSync$2.onDataChange(FeedsterSync.java:107)
    at com.google.firebase.database.zzp.onDataChange(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzegf.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeia.zzbyc(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeig.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: write failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
    at libcore.io.Posix.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.Posix.write(Posix.java:258)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.write(BlockGuardOs.java:313)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:497)
    ... 16 more
```

I have also set both read and write permission as below

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Could somebody please point out what is wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance!

Here is the code using which, I am calling the `LogBack` code

```
FileOutputStream fos;
String logMsg;
try {
   fos = getActivity().openFileOutput(Constants.BACKUP_LOG, Context.MODE_APPEND);
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The below lines of code are inside catch blocks and where ever I am writing any log statements..

```
logMsg = "Error in FetchRssItemsTask : \n" + e.getStackTrace();
Log.e(TAG, logMsg);
LogBackup.getLogBackup(fos).writeLog(TAG+" "+logMsg);
```

Comment: `Here fos is obtained using openFileOutput method.` Please show complete code.

Comment: `I have also set both read and write permission as below`. Those are not needed if you only use `openFileOutput()`.

Comment: `Thanks in advance!` O. I did not see that before. Bad habit.

Comment: Also show how you call that class and its members.

Comment: Actually, my studio is being updated, I am unable to get the code right now, will update the code in a few minutes.

Comment: Hey I have added the code(from fragment) you had asked, please check and let me know.

Comment: `fos = getActivity().openFileOutput(Constants.BACKUP_LOG, Context.MODE_APPEND);` If you ask for help ten do not use things like Constants.BACKUP_LOG as we do not know what the value would be. Just use a string literal so we can see.

Comment: `logMsg = "Error in FetchRssItemsTask : \n" + e.getStackTrace();` Should not that be in the catch block? And if you have a catch then return. At the moment it looks as if you continue with the code as if nothing has happened.

Comment: You are living dangerous with all those static fields and functions. You better make a singleton class. `

Comment: here, BACKUP_LOG = "FeedsterLog.txt"
and yes I am using the logMsg inside the catch block, I just didn't put that here just to make it small. sorry for that, will update it..

Comment: in `writeLog()` method you are closing your stream

Comment: Yes good catch! I just wanted to tell that ;-).  `writeLog()` can only be called one time now.

Comment: Actually, I am using the openFileOutput method before every log.
So, it is going to open the FOS everytime.

Comment: Yep, looks like that was the issue, I put the openFileOutput statement inside the getLogBackup method and it is working fine now. I guess there were one or two places where I forgot to put the openFileOutput stmt.

Comment: no, no, no, if you want it to be just for one log, then open and close your stream in the same method (`writeLog` in your case), otherwise you will have opened streams if you just call `getLogBackup` and dont call `writeLog`

Comment: okay, better to just open it inside writeLog.. Thanks!